# iOS sound on button problems on second click

Tags: ios, avaudioplayer

I have code which plays a sound after I clicked a button. When I click this button a second time first comes a thing like a reset or so.

What I want: Every time I click the button I want to play the sound immediately without reset button.

My code:

```
-(IBAction)playfrosch {

if (gestartet == 0) {
    gestartet = 1;

    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/frosch.mp3", [[NSBundle mainBundle]resourcePath]]];

    NSError *error;
    audioPlayerfrosch = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error:&error];
    audioPlayerfrosch.numberOfLoops = 0;

    [audioPlayerfrosch play];
    [startfrosch setTitle:@"Frosch" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

}   else {

    gestartet = 0;
    [startfrosch setTitle:@"Nochmal?" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

}

I think my problems are the part after "else".

Comment: Can you elaborate on "When I click this button a second time first comes a thing like a reset or so"?  What are you trying to do and what (in detail) actually happens?

Comment: This is not related to Xcode.

Comment: Hi wilson, wehn I click a second time on the button it shows "Nochmal". Then I have to click another time on it to play the sound. I want, that "Nochmal" do not appear. I want to play the sound when I click the button. The first time I click the button it works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a logic problem. Your code only executes the sound play code if gestartet == 0.

So move the sound play code outside of the if statement. Problem solved.